# Doctrine 2 mapping process manipulation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mapping

I want to ask if its clean possible to change the mapping process.
For example, if i have an database, with products and offers, so the relation is 1 product n offers.

I want to get on fetch an product with multiple offers not an collection of offers, instead of i want to get an class named "AggregateOffers" which calculates the highest the lowest price and includes the offers collection.

Did anyone know an good/clean solution?

For an better understanding, [schema.org](http://schema.org/Product) defines the relation between an product an multiple offers, within an aggregateoffer, so i want to abstract them, to generate at the end an json-ld.

My actually design looks like [schema](http://yuml.me/d8d36034.png), as you can see i have an 1-n relation from Product to Offer, what i actually want to get when i read from the DB, is an extended relation.

For example:

Product -> getOffers (should not return an collection of offers, instead it should return an "AggregateOffers" which hold the collection of offers).

The only idea, is to update the "getOffers" function and return die Aggregation class, but this acts not really good on me.

Comment: What have you tried already? What is your existing structure/design? Your question is currently quite vague so might gain more attention with additional information/examples.

Comment: i've update my answer with a link to my structure, and add an example what  i need, thx